# Bulma (css framework) adds iframe height auto and embedded YouTube videos get less height

Tags: css, iframe, frameworks, height, bulma

Bulma added the following line:

```
img, embed, iframe, object, video {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

and I can't figure out how to set embedded YouTube videos to their intended height, because with `height: auto` they get way less height and there is no attribute for `height` that I would know of that would fix it. Because the height of the video gets lower (same size) for every possibility. So I cannot even override it.

[image: embedded YouTube video with Bulma]

Can anyone think of a fix?

Comment: I have this same issue

Comment: @itwasmattgregg Try adding the code from this gist https://gist.github.com/jaicab/8799764

Comment: I can't wrap the iframe in a div because the content comes from wordpress injected into a template by gatsby. I could parse through the content but that gets a little tedious.

Answer (score 6):

I have this same issue, and if you can edit your iframe style, use style height to replace height
before:

```html
<iframe width="500" height="300"  src="//player.bilibili.com/player.html?aid=75317985" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" allowfullscreen="true"> </iframe>
```

after

```html
<iframe style="width:500px;height:300px;" src="//player.bilibili.com/player.html?aid=75317985" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" allowfullscreen="true"> </iframe>
```

And after that, your iframe will not affected by Bulma.min.css.

Answer (score 4):

This solution is answered in the Bulma documentation: https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/image/#arbitrary-ratios-with-any-element

Wrap the iframe in a figure, and add `class="has-ratio"` to the iframe.

Comment: cannot make it `5x3` or `500x315`, for example. So it is generally a bad answer.

Comment: What do you mean @Polv? The documentation states the ratio can be "arbitrary"

Comment: @Pakman I see that I actually can choose the number, either via self-compile SASS, or reverse engineer the CSS. Otherwise, has-ratio just mean you can apply to any element.